# IVectorView of StorageFile becomes null after OpenReadAsync in a loop (possible winrt bug)

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I am creating a runtime class inside the BlankApp project template that opens a `IVectorView<StorageFile>` that it receives by reference as a parameter. It then loops over the vector in order to read from the files. However when I try to use the vector after the call to read, it throws a read access violation.

The reason why I think this is a bug is because it only happens when I compile using the x64 configuration of the BlankApp project. In x86 the exception is not thrown.

This is pretty easy to reproduce so it would be nice if someone else could confirm if this happens to them.

```
//test_class.idl

[bindable]
[default_interface]
runtimeclass test_class
{
    test_class();

    Windows.Foundation.IAsyncAction read_files(Windows.Foundation.Collections.IVectorView<Windows.Storage.StorageFile> files);
}
```

```cpp
//test_class.cpp
Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction test_class::read_files(Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorView<Windows::Storage::StorageFile> const& files)
{
    for (auto& file : files)
    {
        auto res = files;
        auto stream = co_await file.OpenReadAsync();
        auto res2 = files; // read access violation. this->**m_ptr** was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
    }

    co_return;
}
```

```cpp
//MainPage.cpp
Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction MainPage::onclick_button(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const & sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const & args)
{
    BlankApp1::test_class m_test_class = winrt::make<BlankApp1::implementation::test_class>();

    Windows::Storage::Pickers::FileOpenPicker picker;
    picker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L".bmp");

    Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorView<Windows::Storage::StorageFile> files = co_await picker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();

    co_await m_test_class.read_files(files);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you're passing an arg by reference to an asynchronous method. During the `co_await`, the calling function (`onclick_button`) may have cleaned up the objects your reference is referring to, basically resulting in a dangling reference. To avoid this, your coroutines should accept parameters by value, not by reference.

See the following section for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency#parameter-passing

Comment: If I understand correctly, projected types are the moral equivalent of `std::shared_ptr`. In that case, there are 2 immediate consequences, that aren't explicitly called out in the documentation: `1` Passing by value is fairly cheap (a pointer copy, plus bookkeeping). `2` Passing by value logically amounts to passing by reference; no new implementation instance is created, and the projected type copy still references the original implementation. Am I correct, or is my mental model broken?

Comment: That's roughly correct. Passing by value doesn't involve anything crazy like a heap allocation. But the "bookkeeping" still carries a decidedly non-trivial performance cost. Both the addref and release involve a virtual function call and the reference count is typically interlocked. So, pass by const ref whenever possible, but also don't lose too much sleep when pass by value is required.